# When should a shared_ptr be passed as a raw pointer?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I was reading about how shared pointers should be passed around.
I came across this [link](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) which states

> Guideline: Use a non-const shared_ptr& parameter only to modify the
> shared_ptr. Use a const shared_ptr& as a parameter only if you’re not
> sure whether or not you’ll take a copy and share ownership; otherwise
> use widget* instead (or if not nullable, a widget&).

I had a two questions regarding the above mentioned statement

**Question 1:**

It states

> .. otherwise use widget* instead (or if not nullable, a widget&).

Does this mean if we have something like this

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> f = std::make_shared<foo>();
```

And we need to pass it to a different method. That method should have the signature like

```
void doSomething(foo* ptr); //assuming its nullable
```

so to use it will be

```
doSomething(f.get());
```

Is this correct ? If so then would this not be dangerous ? if the reference count of f goes to 0 then ptr would basically be invalid ? In which situation would I want to create a method that takes in a raw pointer ? Why would I want to pass a smart pointer around like that ?

**Question 2**
What does modify mean here ? How do I modify a shared pointer ?

> Use a non-const shared_ptr& parameter only to modify the shared_ptr

Comment: All use of pointers, raw non-owning or smart, can be considered "dangerous" if used wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give **Question 2** a try: Modifying a shared pointer means assigning a different object instance (and dropping ownership of the previously owned pointer).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int
main() {
    using intptr = std::shared_ptr<int>;
    intptr p = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    auto func = [](intptr &x) { x = std::make_shared<int>(6);};

    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    func(p);
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All those are considerations of  streamlining code and readability, where function signature is used as a clue to what function is meant for.

If a function requires a shared state of pointer to object while accessing it, it have no practical sense to pass it as shared pointer unless function is meant to  grab ownership on it. I.e. function `foo()` with signature

```
void  foo( std::shared_ptr<Object> p);  // it shares ownership
```

would grab control of Object instance, because parameter `p` is a *local variable* for `foo()`.

Functions with non-const reference signature rise questions what they actually mean to do:

```
void  foo( std::shared_ptr<Object>& p);  // new storage may be assigned
```

They can change object owned by shared pointer `p` OR can change - *modify* - pointer itself by calling its `reset()` method. The guideline offers to use this for the latter because using shared state to dereference pointer got its cost. The former task easily can be done by raw reference:

```
void  foo( Object& p);  // object may change but occupies same storage
```

Raw pointer would make sense if result of `.get()` can be `nullptr`, otherwise controlled objects are better to be passed by reference.

Finally, constant reference allows to make another shared or weak pointer or to change the object, but doesn't allow to modify original pointer. This signature suggest that foo() *may* do the former.

```
void  foo(const shared_ptr<Object>& p); // p cannot be changed but may be shared
```

Comment: So if we are going to be using a .reset() in a function then we might as well use the signature `void  foo( Object& p);` but if we are going to be re-assigning a shared pointer then use `foo( std::shared_ptr<Object>& p);` is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @MistyD What? How you gonna use reset when you don't have pointer? `reset()` member is one of ways to reassign , aside from creating a temporary by `make_shared` and assigning it